# Как изменить родительский элемент, при hover дочернего?

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/703x685");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}

.child-left,
.child-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

// Есть какой-нибудь трюк, что бы на чистом css поменять css код(в данном случае background-img) родительского элемента? пример ниже не работает
.child-left::hover {
  .parent {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100")
  }
}

.child-right::hover {
  .parent {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200")
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">1</div>
  <div class="child-right">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не думаю, что чистым `css`-ом это возможно в принципе..

Comment: Не возможно на чистом css....!!!!!!!

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать именно этот случай, с подменой background?

Answer (score 1):

В css сделать зависимость от предка к родителю невозможно. Но можно сделать что-то наподобие вот этого:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/703x685");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.child-left,
.child-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.child-left:hover~.bg {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
  background-color: green;
}

.child-right:hover~.bg {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-left">1</div>
  <div class="child-right">2</div>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: от меня +5, только будет ли без bg работать ...

Comment: @Максим-Ленский, к сожалению без этого дополнительного дива работать не будет, именно для этого он и добавлен. Если пробовать делать через before/after например, то тоже работать не будет так как хочется, тк границы ссылки наведения без обрезки фона невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Изменить родительский элемент при hover дочернего можно при помощи [псевдокласса :has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style>
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/703x685");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
}

.child-left, .child-right {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
}

.parent:has(.child-left:hover) {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
}

.parent:has(.child-right:hover) {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
}
</style></head>
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child-left">1</div>
        <div class="child-right">2</div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Красавчик, очень помогло. Спасибо @fedorch